# How does index assignment to nodes work in Spark with mapPartitionsWithIndex()?

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, partitioning, rdd

I am trying to coordinate GPU execution on a Spark cluster. In order to achieve this I need each task/partition to only use a specific GPU slot per system. Each system has 4 GPUs, and the easiest way I have found to achieve this is by doing a mapPartitionsWithIndex() on the rdd with the data, and then using the index as the gpu slot.

My question is if I can depend on the indexes to always be assigned in order to the worker nodes? Is there any documentation that refers to this?

Quick example:

```
from pyspark import SparkContext
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext

sc = SparkContext(appName="sample")
sqlContext = SQLContext(sc)

def print_partition_info(idx, part):
    print "Index: {} - Partition data: {}".format(idx, part)
    for p in part:
        yield p

data = [1,1,1,2,2,2, 20, 30, 40, 100]
partitions = 4
rdd = sc.parallelize(data, partitions)
# rdd = rdd.coalesce(len(partition_keys))
rdd2 = rdd.mapPartitionsWithIndex(print_partition_info)
```

Lets pretend the printed output of running an action on rdd2 is

```
Index: 0 - Partition data: [1,1]  
Index: 1 - Partition data: [1,2]  
Index: 2 - Partition data: [2,2]  
Index: 3 - Partition data: [20,30,40,100]
```

When these partitions get sent out to workers (say 2 workers), will they always be in order as in...
Worker 1 partitions = 1, 2
Worker 2 partitions = 3, 4

Expanding on that will the partitions always be ordered for say a cluster of 10 or 50 nodes?

Finally here is a slide that seems to support this technique:

[image]
[slides - check #52](http://www.slideshare.net/continuumio/gpu-computing-with-apache-spark-and-python)

Answer (score 0):

Short answer: No. In a cluster, the RessourceManager (YARN most of the time) will use a worker if it is available, and it is not always the case when your system is multi-user, or if you have already started a job in a subset of your cluster. So you can't bind a worker with an index.

Thus, I am pretty sure that index 0 will bind to the first partition in your data, and so on. An expert will correct me if I'm wrong.

Comment: I was going to add my own answer since I saw this technique used by someone else for GPU computation on Spark, but have not gotten around to it since I am still testing it, and I am only using a stand-alone Spark cluster. But from my testing so far, mapPartitionsWithIndex always assigns the indexes in order to each node. The first node that is available will still be picked, but they always stay in order, this way a cluster with 10 systems can assign the GPU in each system with index % gpu_count. I will post a link soon.